# Deck of Cards and shuffle method

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement deck of cards and create a shuffle method for it. Everything is working fine when I'm writing it in the main method but when I'm trying to do it using different methods then even after using shuffle method I'm getting the original sequence of the cards (it is not shuffling). What I'm doing wrong?

```
import java.util.*;

public class DeckOfCards {

    String[] suits = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
    String[] ranks = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

    private int[] cards;
    public DeckOfCards(){

        cards = new int[52];
        for(int i =0; i < 52; i++){
            cards[i] = i;
        }
    }

    public void shuffle(int num){

        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
            int m = (int)Math.random() * cards.length;
            int n = (int)Math.random() * cards.length;

            int t = cards[m];
            cards[m] = cards[n];
            cards[n] = t;
        }

    }

    public void display(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
            String suit = suits[cards[i]/13];
            String rank = ranks[cards[i] % 13];
            System.out.println(rank+" of "+suit);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        DeckOfCards d = new DeckOfCards();
        d.display();
        d.shuffle(50);
        d.display();

    }

}
```

Comment: Note : you can also use `Collections.shuffle`.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle:  That'd be the best approach if they had a proper collection of `Card`s.

Comment: @Arnaud Thanks, I'm aware of that but I'm preparing for an Interview so was trying to implement that rather that using Collections.shuffle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This

```
int m = (int)Math.random() * cards.length;
```

is always zero, because it calculates `(int) Math.random()` (zero) and then multiplies it by `cards.length`.

What you meant was:

```
int m = (int) (Math.random() * cards.length);
int n = (int) (Math.random() * cards.length);
```

Answer (score -3):

instead of relying on math.random, java has a random class that uses a seed for its own randomization:

```
Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

int m = random.nextInt(cards.length);
int n = random.nextInt(cards.length);
```